# Maya Python, Renaming joints: more than one object matches name

Tags: python, maya

Ok, so I get two errors whenever I try to run this script: but before I get ahead of myself: lets get to my objective.

create two joint chains, names are unimportant: but essentially I know that you can use brackets to list and isolate joint chains with matching children names. Instead my script seems to be ignoring the brackets and giving me the error anyways. I've tried every different flag for list relatives: but all that seems to do is change the error to something else.

I know that if this script was properly working it would only work on one joint chain because of the hardcoded names: but the script I'm pulling it from has name prefexes tied to the GUI to avoid hardcoding and allow adaptive naming: I'm only using the hardcoded as an example for this script. My complaint is this script doesn't work on ANY joint chain because I keep getting the error "more than one object matches name."

To run the script,save the following code as a .py in your maya documents script folder, restart your copy of maya, then open a new python tab and run the first three lines of code above import maya.cmds

```
'''
import exampleScriptTemplate
reload (exampleScriptTemplate)
exampleScriptTemplate.gui()
'''

import maya.cmds as cmds

if cmds.window("buildWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("buildWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("buildWin",t='DS_pvFinder',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.button(w=300,label='build placement curve',c=printMultiple)
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

def printMultiple(*args):
    
    root = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    child = cmds.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    child.append(root)
    child.reverse()
    limbJnt = child

    print (child)

    armroot = []
    for j in limbJnt:
        wstJnt = cmds.rename(child[3], 'wrist_BIND')
        elbJnt = cmds.rename(child[2], 'elbow_BIND')
        sdrJnt = cmds.rename(child[1], 'shoulder_BIND')
        clvJnt = cmds.rename(child[0], 'clavicle_BIND')
        armroot.append(j)

    return armroot
```

I know I'm in the right ballpark. I just need to know how to properly use the brackets  to store the list of what i'm selecting instead of searching all of worldspace and breaking.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you loop through `limbJnt`, but individually hard-code numbers to rename with `child`?? You probably don't need the loop at all. Haggi is correct, with `cmds` it's best to rename from the leaf and work your way up the hierarchy to avoid losing reference to other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is incomplete, no window is opening, so I tried only the *printMultiple* function which causes a *Error: No object matches name* in my case.

Your code cannot work like this since you mix hardcoded names with a loop which does nothing. I suppose your main problem is the order of your renamings. The child array contains absolute names like:

```
[u'joint1', u'|joint1|joint2', u'|joint1|joint2|joint3']
```

If you now rename child[0] to 'clavicle_BIND', all the remaining elements in the list become invalid because their real names in the scene now look like this:

```
[u'clavicle_BIND', u'|clavicle_BIND|joint2', u'|clavicle_BIND|joint2|joint3']
```

What results in an error at the second rename line. Inverting the order sovles this problem, first rename the leaf node, then the ones above.

Comment: Hey @haggi krey, I updated the script with instructions on how to run it: my apologies for not noticing that earlier. What do you mean exactly by inverting the order? do you mean reversing the order of the child joint selector list or do you mean the order I named the bones?

Comment: You rename first the top joint, clavicle. Rename the leaf joint, the wrist first.

Comment: I see what you mean, I reverse the list and it did indeed change the names: but now I get error saying "/maya/2020/scripts\exampleScriptTemplate.py line 32: No object matches name" is there a way I can get this to run without getting the error at the end?

Comment: Could you update the script with your changes so that we can follow your progress and see what's wong?

Comment: sure thing, I just updated the script. It renames the joints just fine: but I still get an error message

Comment: What exactly do you need the loop for? In the first iteration the joints are renamed from the old name to the new name, in the second iteration the joints are renamed form the old name to the new name but... the old ones do not exist any more, they are already renamed. I suggest to remove the loop.